# External .JS and .CSS not working with a newly uploaded html file on Digital Ocean

Tags: html, css, node.js, digital-ocean

There's nothing fancy about the HTML, JS or CSS code. It all works fine if I embed the css inside the HTML file, but when linking to the external file it doesn't work.

Just uploaded it all to Digital Ocean, so I'm not sure if there are any special configurations I need to make to enable these external files to work.

Here's the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>v1</h2>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the browser console show an error? How is the DO droplet configured?

Comment: It's an ubuntu server. I get the error: Failed to load resource: the server <IP Address> responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Hmm, so I might have uploaded the css files in the wrong directory. Though they are in the same directory as the html file, and I have no trouble updating that one and having it work.

Comment: can you browse to the CSS or JS files in the browser? I mean, using the same address, except with `/style.css` at the end instead of the address of the HTML file?

Comment: Hmm no, gives me a "Cannot GET /style.css".

Comment: permissions problem?

Comment: have already tried changing permission, unfortunately that isn't the problem. It seems as though it isn't locating the file in the same folder as the .html file.

Comment: Any errors in the error or access logs on the server?

Comment: are all of these files in the same folder? -- gotta ask haha

Comment: That error sounds like an Express one, are you running that? Did you remember to load the `express.static` middleware and configure it properly?

Comment: All files are in the same folder yes :) and I'm not running Express. I'm very puzzled